# Rails 'nested' association search

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This question must have been asked million times already, but i just couldn't find the answer :(

Assuming I have 3 models:

```
class Country
  has_many :cities
end

class City
  has_many :companies
end

class Company
  belongs_to :city
end
```

I can fetch companies in the given City by `City.first.companies`, but what I would like is to be able to fetch all companies for given Country, like `Country.first.companies`

What I was able to achieve is to write a method in `Country` model:

```
 def companies
   @companies = []
   cities.all.each{ |c| @companies << c.companies unless c.companies.empty? }
   @companies
 end
```

But it returns array of arrays of Company objects. I could have also added `country_id` column as a FK for Country model, like

```
class Country
  has_many :cities
  has_many :companies
end

class Company
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :country
end
```

but that doesn't look very DRY.

I would like to receive array of Company objects for given Country. I'm pretty sure that there is a Rails way to achieve this. What would it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `has_many through` association.

```
class Country
  has_many :companies, :through => :cities
```

Now you can use `Country.last.companies`.

Comment: oh dear... It is so obvious, I just did not know `:through` association works this way...